# python struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= USHRT_MAX

Tags: python

I'm using python to do one test:

```
print struct.pack('1H', 101000)
```

It shows me this error:

```
struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= USHRT_MAX
```

I'm confused about this, as I know 1H means unsigned short which means this first bit can be used, so the max scope of 1H should be 0 <= number <= (2 << 16) - 1 (that means 131071), so why does it show me this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum isn't `(2<<16) - 1`, it's 2^16 - 1. Or, if you prefer to write it as a shift, `(1<<16) - 1`. The number two is already shifted left one place. The maximum value for an unsigned short (16 bits) is 65535.